# Why aren't Ctrl+m and Ctrl+q used in bash shortcuts?

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts

Recently I've been reviewing the bash shortcuts keys, and trying to find an appropriate one for my tmux activate key.

I find it interesting that `ctrl + m` and `ctrl + q` are not used in bash shortcuts, according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell).

Why they are not used? I feel `ctrl + m` is quite handy.

Are these two combinations intended by design for `DIY (define it yourself)` usage? Or there is another story?

Comment: Using `ALT + m` is even more convenient imho.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ctrl+M sends the same character(RET) as the Enter key in terminal. Programs have no way to tell them apart, so these keys cannot be configured separately.

Ctrl+Q is already used for [XON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_flow_control) by default, so it cannot be used by Bash, but you should still be able to use it in tmux, because tmux uses raw input mode.

A GUI program could read from the keyboard, that Key m has been pressed with modifier Ctrl and use Ctrl+m as a shortcut, but a shell or any terminal program recieves the Ctrl+Key combinations just as ascii characters from 0 to 26

```
Ctrl+@ = 0
Ctrl+A = 1
Ctrl+B = 2
```

and so on. You can try this to see the values

```
cat ctrlkeys <<EOF
^A^B^C^D^E^F
EOF
od -c ctrlkeys
0000000 001 002 003 004 005 006  \n
```

To enter the values press Ctrl+v before Ctrl+[a-f] to get them uninterpreted as a raw value.

When you look at the ascii(7) table you can see the control codes in a table with the corresponding characters @..Z on the left. For example

```
015   13    0D    CR  '\r' (carriage ret)     115   77    4D    M
```

or

```
011   9     09    HT  '\t' (horizontal tab)   111   73    49    I
```

The next layer that interprets control codes before bash is stty (change and print the terminal settings)

```
stty -a
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O;
```

see stty(1) for the meanings of `lnext` or `start` and `stop`.

Also see readline(3) as bash and other GNU cli programs use that library to control input lines and of course bash(1) /READLINE, the readline section of the bash manual page.

*Note: XYZ(NUM) means manual page XYZ from section NUM, so the result of `man NUM XYZ`.*

Comment: Bash has a default binding for C-s (XOFF), so they could have put one for C-q as well.

Comment: Actually, by default, the GNU Readline library that Bash uses binds `C-q` to the same thing as `C-v`, a clone of the Emacs function `quoted-insert` which is useful for figuring out the escape codes generated by keys and key combos. Here's the relevant part of the Readline manual: https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC9